# How to "duplicate" the content of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have an array :

```
var array_1 = ['c','b','a'];
```

What is the best way to transform `array_1` into

```
['c','c','b','b','a','a'];
```

or even

```
['c','c','c','b','b','b','a','a','a'];
```

Comment: You must've tried something so post it

Comment: @zer00ne sure, some stupid loops, just looking here for a smarter answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [`fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) like this:

```js
function duplicate(arr, times) {
  return arr.flatMap(n => Array(times).fill(n))
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(duplicate([1,2,3], 2)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(duplicate([1,2,3], 3)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the 'new' `.flat()` you can reduce an array to one dimension and to multiple the elements just map each element to an array of these elements.

```js
var arr1 = ['c', 'b', 'a'];

var arr2 = arr1.map(e => ([e, e, e])).flat();

console.log(arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a question of style, typically when you iterate over an array and want to perform additive operations you would use the [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method...

```
const ar1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
const ar2 = ar1.reduce((ac, cv) => [...ac, cv, cv, cv], [])
```

... though map, forEach, etc. would also work.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the original array, and for each character, create a new array using `Array(x).fill(c)`. Where `x` is the number of duplicates, and `c` is the character that you want to duplicate. Then concatenate each new array together.

Answer (score 0):

Using simple **forEach** and **for loop**.

You can duplicate your array with a function call with your array and the number of times that you want to duplicate.

```js
const myArray = ['c', 'b', 'a'];

const resultArr1 = duplicate(myArray, 2);
console.log(resultArr1);

const resultArr2 = duplicate(myArray, 3);
console.log(resultArr2);

function duplicate(arr, times) {
  let duplicateArray = [];
  arr.forEach(item => {
    for(i=0; i < times; i++) {
      duplicateArray.push(item);
    }
  });
  return duplicateArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static char[] duplicateAnarray(char arr[], int duplicacyCount) {
    char arrnew[] = new char[((arr.length) * duplicacyCount)];
    char temp;

    int p = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < arr.length; k++) {
        for (int i = p; i < arrnew.length; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < duplicacyCount; j++) {
                arrnew[i + j] = arr[k];

            }
            p = i + duplicacyCount;
            break;

        }
    }
    return arrnew;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array_1 = ['a','b','c']   
/* if array has numbers array_1 = [1,2,3] both case are handled and you can change duplicacy number for elements.*/

getResult = (array_1,elemDuplicacyNumber)=>{

    return  elemDuplicacyNumber <= 0 ? array_1 : array_1.reduce((curr, acc) =>{

                    let arr1 = Array(elemDuplicacyNumber).fill(curr);
                    let arr2 = Array(elemDuplicacyNumber).fill(acc);

                     arr1 = isNaN(curr) ? arr1   : arr1.map(Number);
                     arr2 = isNaN(acc) ?  arr2 : arr2.map(Number);

                    return (Array.isArray(curr)?curr : arr1 ).concat(arr2)
            })

}

console.log( getResult(array_1,5) )
```